# iBeacon detected in Locate app but not in Beacon Tools

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, transmission

I am trying to transmit the major minor id from device making it an iBeacon using library

```
compile 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2.9.2@aar'
```

the code

```
if (mBeaconTransmitter != null) {
            mBeaconTransmitter.stopAdvertising();
        }
        BeaconParser beaconParser=new BeaconParser();
        mBeaconTransmitter = new BeaconTransmitter(getApplicationContext(), new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
        int flag= mBeaconTransmitter.checkTransmissionSupported(this);
        Log.v("@@@WWe"," BEacon Test "+flag);
        Beacon beacon = new Beacon.Builder()
                .setId1("2f234454-cf6d-4a0f-adf2-f4911ba9ffa6")
                .setId2(majorID)//Major
                .setId3(minorID)//Minor
                .setBluetoothName("Vyas Pratik")
                .setBeaconTypeCode(533)
                .setManufacturer(0x0075) // Choose a number of 0x00ff or less as some devices cannot detect beacons with a manufacturer code > 0x00ff
                .setTxPower(-59)
                .setMultiFrameBeacon(true)
                .build();
//                .setId2(minorID)//Major Try
//                .setId3(majorID)//Minor Try
                //.setBluetoothAddress(bluetoothManager.getAdapter().getAddress())
                //    .setDataFields(Arrays.asList(new Long[]{0l}))


        mBeaconTransmitter.startAdvertising(beacon, new AdvertiseCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStartSuccess(AdvertiseSettings settingsInEffect) {
                super.onStartSuccess(settingsInEffect);
                Log.v("@@@WWe"," Sucess "+settingsInEffect.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartFailure(int errorCode) {
                super.onStartFailure(errorCode);
                Log.v("@@@WWe"," Error "+String.valueOf(errorCode));
            }
        });
```

However, my beacon using this code is detected in Locate app but not in beacon tools app /nearby (Google app).please guide me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several trial and error trick, I got to a solution for this problem, the UUID, and manufacturer id was wrong.
so I changed it to below value and the beacon is now detecting in google near by and beacon tools aswell

```
 Beacon beacon = new Beacon.Builder()
//                .setId1("2f234454-cf6d-4a0f-adf2-f4911ba9ffa6")
//                .setManufacturer(0x0118) // Choose a number of 0x00ff or less as some devices cannot detect beacons with a manufacturer code > 0x00ff
                .setId1("6d234454-cf6d-4a0f-adf2-f4911ba9ffa6")
                .setManufacturer(0x4c) // Choose a number of 0x00ff or less as some devices cannot detect beacons with a manufacturer code > 0x00ff
                .setId2(majorID)//Major
                .setId3(minorID)//Minor
                .setBluetoothName("Vyas Pratik")
                .setTxPower(-59)
                .build();
```

Comment: Glad you found it.  Yes, using iBeacon you must set the manufacturer code to Apple's code.

Comment: yep , setting manufacturer code and correct uuid made my code working